# How would I create a scope using a join that will return only records where all of a has_many relationship read as true (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, scope

I've been trying to write a scope for this model to help filter and find only records where all participants (has_many relationship) have a value for acknowledged_at. The problem I run into is that when trying to do that, I get all records where *at least* one participant has a value for acknowledged_at. How would I adjust this scope to only return ones where all participants have a value in acknowledged_at?

The scope in question:

```rb
scope :completed, -> { joins(:example_participants).where('example_participants.acknowledged_at is not null') }
```

I've tried inverting and changing this a few ways but have yet to get a result that filters out records with only one participant that has acknowledged_at present.

to reiterate my goal is to have only records where *all* participants have a value present in acknowledged_at

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it in the other direction.

```rb
scope :completed, -> {
  where.not(id: ExampleParticipant.select(:this_model_id).where(acknowledged_at: nil))
}
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the response! 

I might be mistaken but I don't think this will help me with my current goal, as I need to have a full list of all relevant base records that meet the requirement. That being having all of their participants (has_many relationship) that have a value in acknowledged at.

Comment: @engineersmnky Hey there, this will return all records that have at least one participant that meets those requirements. I need a list of records where each participant has acknowledged_at filled in not just some.

Comment: @ZachariahWhite sorry reading too fast. This answer seems correct as it will exclude any of your models where any participant has not acknowledged. Resulting in a list of only the models where every participant has acknowledged.

Comment: @smathy It might be that I don't fully understand this response, how would I use this as a scope for a filter? I'm unsure what to place in the :this_model_id spot to have this be something I can call.

Comment: Well you wrote "I've been trying to write a scope for this model to help filter..." but you never gave the name of "this model" but that `:this_model_id` is the name of the foreign key in the `example_participants` table that's pointing back at "this model" - whatever that is.

Comment: The only _possible_ issue with what I've provided is that it will also return any `ThisModel` records that have NO associated `example_participants`. Not sure if you want that or not, it's ambiguous in your reqs.

Comment: understood, sorry I was trying to get a better understanding of the code. This worked wonderfully after that understanding. 

Great work and thank you for the help!

Comment: @smathy the minor caveat you mentioned could be easily solved with a join.

Comment: @engineersmnky yep, a `distinct.join` probably best, but just wanted to mention it.

Comment: All good @ZachariahWhite - glad I could help.